# Sending an adapter from Activity to ListActivity

Tags: android, adapter

I dont know whether my present approach is correct or not... I am having two classes one that extends the Activity and the other that extends the ListActivity. Now I wanted to sort my list in the ListActivity when I press a button present in the Activity class layout. What are the possible ways.. presently I am trying to send an adapter from the Activity class to ListActivity but it is failing me. So any other ideas. Expecting an answer soon...Thanx in advance.

Comment: Putting as extra, like @Ralgha said, probably would be the best way... But you can also set a static list items and sort them, then you can call notifyDataSetChanged as well. Both will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Two options that I see offhand.

1) Put the sort button in the ListActivity's layout so it's all in the same Activity.

2) When they push the sort button in Activity 1, put the sort method into the Intent that you launch the ListActivity with as an extra.  Read that extra in your ListActivity and sort accordingly.

Comment: But I dont want the ListActivity to show up ... when you say that I sent the adapter as an extra to intent then it will also call the onCreate method for the ListActivity which I dont want to. I just want it to happen in the background.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The whole point of a ListActivity is to show a list to the user.

Comment: Okay let me give a situation... Consider a playlist button... the playlist button when clicked in the Activity class will call the ListActivity via intent. Okay done. Now there is this shuffle button... that will shuffle my ArrayList which will again be fed in an adapter and this adapter is what I want to sent to the ListActivity but I dont want it to open everytime I select or deselect the shuffle button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button or inflate a layout and then add it as a header,  something like

```
    Button sort = new Button(this);
    sort.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //....
        }
    });
    ListView lv;
    getListView().addHeaderView(sort)


    setListAdapter(...)
```

Comment: I am not getting the approach.. what is exactly happening here in the code? Considering you have given the button name as sort then what does addHeaderView() does exactly?

Comment: it adds a header view to the listview. the header view is before any of your list items.  Using this way you shouldnt need to switch from using a ListActivity to Activity class